# How can I get a value outside the function

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

```
L1=[]
L2=[]
def big_data(query,x,y):
    x = []
    r = requests.get("http://bigdata.com/metrics/?" + query)
    r0 = r.json()[0][u'datapoints']
    returned_data = r0[17:]
    for datapoint1 in returned_data:
        x.append(datetime.fromtimestamp(datapoint1[1]).strftime('%I%P').lstrip('0').upper())
    y =[item[0] for item in returned_data]
    print(x)
    print(y)
 big_data(domain,L1,L2)
 print(L1)
 print(L2)

When I am running above script I am able to getting a value for x and y but its not giving me anything for L1 and L2.

I am not able to recall what basic thing I am missing here, Can someone please let me know what I am missing here. 

Output I am getting is something like this:-
   x =  ['4PM', '5PM', '6PM', '7PM']
   y =  [291783, 3090123, 2736213, 105331]

L1 = []
L2 = []
```

I am not able to recall what basic thing I am missing here, Can someone please let me know what I am missing here

Comment: put this `return (x, y)` inside on last line of your func big_data    and    `l1, l2 = big_data(domain,L1,L2)`

Comment: @Tanmayjain Negative, that doesn't work I already tried that

Comment: https://pasteboard.co/HJ7cKDH.png

Comment: If this not what u wanted then I might have misunderstood you.

Comment: Doing `x = []` as the first line of your function makes it entirely pointless to have passed `x` as a parameter to the function; you've thrown away whatever value was given when the function was called.  Same thing with the assignment to `y` later on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Didn't try guessing what "domain" was defined as so I couldn't run it. Have you tried passing the x and y through the function with return? Like this:

```
def big_data(query,x,y):
    # blahblahblah
    return [x,y]

L1,L2 = big_data(domain,L1,L2)
print(L1)
print(L2)
```